# no suitable conversion function from "CvTermCriteria" to "int" exists

Tags: opencv3.0, camera-calibration, calibration

How could I solve the error?

I use program that made for OpenCV 2.x but I compile it on OpenCV 3.0, and error appeared.
I change CvTermCriteria to TermCriteria::TermCriteria but thats not working.
How could I change CvTermCriteria to be int?

Hope anyone could help me. Thanks

Error appeared at this part:

```
cvStereoCalibrate( &_objectPoints, &_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints2, &_npoints,&_M1calib, &_D1, &_M2calib, &_D2,imageSize, &_R, &_Tcalib, &_E, &_F, 
    cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
    CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO+CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST + CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH );
```

This is the source code:

```
//--------------Compute for calibration-------------------
    N = n_boards*n;
    objectPoints.resize(N);
    for( i = 0; i < ny; i++ )
        for(j = 0; j < nx; j++ )   objectPoints[i*nx + j] = cvPoint3D32f(i*squareSize, j*squareSize, 0);
    for( i = 1; i < n_boards; i++ ) copy( objectPoints.begin(), objectPoints.begin() + n, objectPoints.begin() + i*n );
    npoints.resize(n_boards,n);

    CvMat _objectPoints = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &objectPoints[0] );
    CvMat _imagePoints1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[0][0] );
    CvMat _imagePoints2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[1][0] );
    CvMat _npoints = cvMat(1, npoints.size(), CV_32S, &npoints[0] );
    cvSetIdentity(&_M1calib);
    cvSetIdentity(&_M2calib);
    cvZero(&_D1);
    cvZero(&_D2);

    printf("\nRunning stereo calibration ...");
    fflush(stdout);
    cvStereoCalibrate( &_objectPoints, &_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints2, &_npoints,&_M1calib, &_D1, &_M2calib, &_D2,imageSize, &_R, &_Tcalib, &_E, &_F, 
    cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
    CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO+CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST + CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH );


    printf("\nDone Calibration");

    cvUndistortPoints( &_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints1,&_M1calib, &_D1, 0, &_M1calib );
    cvUndistortPoints( &_imagePoints2, &_imagePoints2,&_M2calib, &_D2, 0, &_M2calib );


    CvMat* mx1calib = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,imageSize.width, CV_32F );
    CvMat* my1calib = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,imageSize.width, CV_32F );
    CvMat* mx2calib = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,imageSize.width, CV_32F );
    CvMat* my2calib = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,imageSize.width, CV_32F );

    double R1[3][3], R2[3][3], P1[3][4], P2[3][4];
    CvMat _R1 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R1);
    CvMat _R2 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R2);

        CvMat _P1 = cvMat(3, 4, CV_64F, P1);
        CvMat _P2 = cvMat(3, 4, CV_64F, P2);
        cvStereoRectify( &_M1calib, &_M2calib, &_D1, &_D2, imageSize,&_R, &_Tcalib,&_R1, &_R2, &_P1, &_P2, &_Qcalib,0/*CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY*/ );

        cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M1calib,&_D1,&_R1,&_P1,mx1calib,my1calib);
        cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M2calib,&_D2,&_R2,&_P2,mx2calib,my2calib);

        printf("\nSaving matries for later use ...\n");
        cvSave("CalibFile//M1.yml",&_M1calib);
    //  cvSave("CalibFile//D1.yml",&_D1);
    //  cvSave("CalibFile//R1.yml",&_R1);
    //  cvSave("CalibFile//P1.yml",&_P1);

        cvSave("CalibFile//M2.yml",&_M2calib);
    //  cvSave("CalibFile//D2.yml",&_D2);
    //  cvSave("CalibFile//R2.yml",&_R2);
    //  cvSave("CalibFile//P2.yml",&_P2);

        cvSave("CalibFile//Q.yml",&_Qcalib);
        cvSave("CalibFile//T.yml",&_Tcalib);
        cvSave("CalibFile//mx1.yml",mx1calib);
        cvSave("CalibFile//my1.yml",my1calib);
        cvSave("CalibFile//mx2.yml",mx2calib);
        cvSave("CalibFile//my2.yml",my2calib);
```

Comment: Please show the code.... See how to do a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the last two parameters of `stereoCalibrate`

---

In OpenCV >= 3.0, the signature of `stereoCalibrate` changed, and **you need to simply swap the last two parameters**, `flags` and `criteria`.

> **Obsolete C version, OpenCV < 3.0**
>
> C: double cvStereoCalibrate(const CvMat* object_points, const CvMat* image_points1, const CvMat* image_points2, const CvMat* npoints, CvMat* camera_matrix1, CvMat* dist_coeffs1, CvMat* camera_matrix2, CvMat* dist_coeffs2, CvSize image_size, CvMat* R, CvMat* T, CvMat* E=0, CvMat* F=0, CvTermCriteria term_crit=cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS,30,1e-6), int flags=CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC )
>
> **C++ version, OpenCV < 3.0**
>
> C++: double stereoCalibrate(InputArrayOfArrays objectPoints, InputArrayOfArrays imagePoints1, InputArrayOfArrays imagePoints2, InputOutputArray cameraMatrix1, InputOutputArray distCoeffs1, InputOutputArray cameraMatrix2, InputOutputArray distCoeffs2, Size imageSize, OutputArray R, OutputArray T, OutputArray E, OutputArray F, TermCriteria criteria=TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT+TermCriteria::EPS, 30, 1e-6), int flags=CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC )
>
> **C++ version, OpenCV >= 3.0**
>
> double cv::stereoCalibrate  (   InputArrayOfArrays  objectPoints,
>   InputArrayOfArrays  imagePoints1,
>   InputArrayOfArrays  imagePoints2,
>   InputOutputArray    cameraMatrix1,
>   InputOutputArray    distCoeffs1,
>   InputOutputArray    cameraMatrix2,
>   InputOutputArray    distCoeffs2,
>   Size    imageSize,
>   OutputArray     R,
>   OutputArray     T,
>   OutputArray     E,
>   OutputArray     F,
>   int     flags = CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC,
>   TermCriteria    criteria = TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT+TermCriteria::EPS, 30, 1e-6) 
>   )

---

Your code is using C api, which is **obsolete**. You should really consider to use C++ api now.

Comment: Yeah it works, but now got other error. I think something wrong with the header. The error is above:

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CBlobResult::Filter (class CBlobResult &,int,class COperadorBlob *,int,double,double)" (?Filter@CBlobResult@@QAEXAAV1@HPAVCOperadorBlob@@HNN@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall StereoFunctions::stereoDetect(void)" (?stereoDetect@StereoFunctions@@QAEXXZ)

Comment: This other error has nothing to do with the question... So please ask a new question about that. If my answer solves the problem stated in this question, than please accept the answer.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry. Anyway thank you so much for helping me.